# How I create Reports on WSO2 DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I would like to know how I can use the Reporting capability on DAS, I know the BAM had some reporting but I do not know if DAS has the same capability.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in WSO2 DAS 3.0.1 release and in future there will be a better reporting feature. You can use some third part reporting library such as jsreport [1] and load data by using Analytics REST API [2].

[1] http://jsreport.net/

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Analytics+REST+API+Guide